# Google Apps Script - How to get driving distance from Maps for two points in spreadsheet

Tags: google-maps, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Good evening,

I have a spreadsheet where I record my daily driving mileage when working. The column headings are: Date, Point A, Point B, Point C, Point D, Point E, Point F, Point G, and Trip Mileage.

Currently, I manually use Google Maps to determine driving distance between points.  What I'd like to see happen instead is for a script to pull the points data from my spreadsheet, determine distance between the points and total distance of each trip (i.e. row), and insert the total in the last column.

I believe I have this essentially all set up except I can't figure out how to get the distance data from Google Maps.  From reading similar question, I sense someone might tell me to refer to the Maps Distance Matrix API.  I've referred to this.  I'm a beginner programmer, but it appears to me to be oriented toward apps, not Google docs.  Is this the case?  Or can it be made to serve my project?

Thank you in advance for all of your wonderful advice, comments, suggestions, and encouragement!!!

BTW, here is my code currently:

```
 function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var mileageLogSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Mileage Log");
  var dataRange = mileageLogSheet.getDataRange(); //Returns a Range  corresponding to the dimensions in which data is present. 
  var numRows = dataRange.getNumRows();  
  var numCol = dataRange.getNumColumns(); //numCol = 9.

  //Returns the range with the top left cell at the given coordinates (row, column) with the given number of rows and columns.
  var rangeToCompute = mileageLogSheet.getRange(10, 2, numRows-9, numCol-1); 
  var address1,
      address2;

  for(var rowCoord = 1; rowCoord < numRows-9; rowCoord++){

    for(var colCoord = 1; colCoord < 8; colCoord++){

      if(rangeToCompute.getCell(rowCoord, colCoord).getValue() != ""){
        address1 = rangeToCompute.getCell(rowCoord, colCoord).getValue();
        address2 = rangeToCompute.getCell(rowCoord, colCoord+1).getValue();

        var directions = Maps.newDirectionFinder()
        .setOrigin(address1)
        .setDestination(address2)
        .setMode(Maps.DirectionFinder.Mode.DRIVING)
        .getDirections();

        //Nope, this doesn't work!: 
        var distanceValue =  directions.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value; 

        var totalTripDistance;       
      }

    }
  } 

}
```

Comment: You can get the distance value from the directions.  It's in the directions object.  You can see an example of the directions object at the following documentation page:[Directions JSON](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#JSON)

Are you getting the directions object?  That's the first thing.  I don't know the settings in your spreadsheet, so there's no way anyone can know whether you are getting a directions object.  "Hard Code" an example of the values that are coming from your spreadsheet, and show it in your above code so that people can test your code.

Comment: Very similar question that was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57810486/travel-time-based-on-arrival-time-using-google-spreadsheet-function

Answer (score 0):

You can take use of the [Google Maps WEB API's Direction API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro). Which give you a detail result on direction from point A to point B, which include the distance information you want.

To get started, you need an API KEY for using the Google Maps Direction API. Go to [console.developers.google.com](https://console.developers.google.com/) to create an account, create a project, enable the Directions API in your project and then create a credential (API KEY). You should able to create it as server API key and give it the address 0.0.0.0/0, which means all computer on earth, as long as you keep this project to yourself. For more information on creating API KEYS, you can take a look at [this section](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#api_key).

Then in the spreadsheets, you need to first create the request URL by CONCAT your key, origin   and destination. Here is how I did it:

```
=CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=",SUBSTITUTE(B2," ","+")),"&destination="),SUBSTITUTE(C2," ","+")),"&key="),$A$2)
```

*Note that you need to SUBSTITUTE spaces " " to pluses "+"

Then under the `Tools > Script editor...`, create an empty script and replace everything with the following code, and save:

```
function getDistance(url) {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);
  var distance = data.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text;
  return distance; 
}
```

This is a customized function that parse the Google Maps Direction API JSON result and return the distance information. The JSON usually contains multiple routes and under the first route- routes[0], exist multiple legs and in the first leg- legs[0], exist a distance, which include a text and value field, which are a human readable field, and a integer number that represent the distance in meter.

return to the spreadsheets and you can call `=getDistance(CellWithURL)` to get the distance between two places.

I created [an example here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UbPKs45xAjxR8-LwPUosVISKOpRejABeATph9dUHF2o/edit?usp=sharing), hope it helps.

**ps. somehow it works without the API KEY too.. but you should apply for one for otherwise you violate the ToS.

Comment: This was huge help! Thanks!  Will post my code when I stop getting error when I include waypoints.  That is, this throws an error (even though the link is the waypoints example in documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro):                     `function myFunction() {
  var test = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Boston,MA&destination=Concord,MA&waypoints=Charlestown,MA|Lexington,MA";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(test);  }`        @kaho @sandy good

Comment: In contrast to code in my last post, note that this code (without waypoints) does not throw an error: `function myFunction() { //note: "&key=[APIKEY]" is optional at end of link: var test = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Boston,MA&destinati‌​on=Concord,MA"; var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(test); }`                                                                                    @SandyGood @kaho

Comment: That sounds reasonable.  How can you tell that?

Comment: I tried to take that out and pass one waypoint in and it works, plus when I hard code the multiple waypoint url in, it crash, and said complain my url as invalid argument